# Android Studio - Store or Copy a File direct to ROOT of SD Card or Phone

Tags: java, android, copy, apk

Android Studio - Store or Copy a File direct to ROOT of SD Card or Phone

How can i copy a file from Application Directory to ROOT DIRECTORY of my SD CARD or Phone?
With the Code i found on the internet i only can copy or create in following directory:
"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.filme3/files"
But i want to store in
"/storage/emulated/0"
Or on my external sd card.
"storage/9C33-6BBD"

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
File path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
copyFile(new File(path, "filme1_alle.txt"), new File( path,"testfile.txt"));

public static boolean copyFile(File source, File dest){
        try{
            // Declaration et ouverture des flux
            java.io.FileInputStream sourceFile = new java.io.FileInputStream(source);

            try{
                java.io.FileOutputStream destinationFile = null;

                try{
                    destinationFile = new FileOutputStream(dest);

                    // Lecture par segment de 0.5Mo
                    byte buffer[] = new byte[512 * 1024];
                    int nbLecture;

                    while ((nbLecture = sourceFile.read(buffer)) != -1){
                        destinationFile.write(buffer, 0, nbLecture);
                    }
                } finally {
                    destinationFile.close();
                }
            } finally {
                sourceFile.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false; // Erreur
        }

        return true; // Rsultat OK
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removable micro sd cards are read only since Android KitKat.

Only with Storage Access Framework you can write to them.

On Adroid 11+ root of external storage is not writable. Use the public directories then.

Have a look at MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.